# Using HttpUtility.UrlEncode

Tags: .net, silverlight, urlencode

I'm trying to encode the following string using HttpUtility.UrlEncode;

```
1:7:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:FROM BOUQUET "userbouquet.dbe01.tv" ORDER BY bouquet
```

The result i get is;

```
1%3a7%3a1%3a0%3a0%3a0%3a0%3a0%3a0%3a0%3aFROM+BOUQUET+%22userbouquet.dbe0e.tv%22+ORDER+BY+bouquet
```

So it's converting : to %3a, a space to + and " to %22. According to the documentation on MSDN, : shouldn't be converted. Also i don't understand why a space is being converted to a plus, i thought it should of been a %20.

Any information on what's going on and any possible workarounds?

Note: : should be left as is, a space should be %20 and " should be %22

EDIT: I've found a solution using a simple string replace function, but if someone could still explain why urlencode behaves in this way. Thanks

Comment: `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` is acting as expected. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `+` is a reserved URL character that *as its intended purpose* represents space, so that translation is legal.
- `:` is a reserved character, but isn't being used in the intended purpose way here (AFAIK), so percent-encoding is appropriate.
- `"` is neither reserved nor unreserved (i.e. alphanumeric etc), so percent-encoding is the only option

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you feel you need a workaround.  It is true that the use of + for space whilst legal has been handled poorly by some servers in the past.

You might consider `Uri.EscapeDataString` as an alternative, it still encodes : as %3A ( is uses uppercase for hex values as well) but it encodes space a %20.

BTW, that data looks almost like there is some SQL concatentation going on somewhere, please tell me you aren't really doing that.